# How can I add a set number of Decimals?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script, I want that it'll always return the number with 2 decimal place (I.E 1 = 1.00, 1.1 = 1.10, 1.11 = 1.11)
I've managed to do it for 1 and 1.11, but I can think of a solution that wont take too much space for 1.1.
Thats what I got:

```psh
$Result = $shippingprice % 2
IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $shippingpricestring = "$" + $shippingprice.ToString()
}
else {
  $shippingpricestring = "$" + ($shippingprice | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}
$Result = $itemprice % 2
IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $itempricestring = "$" + $itemprice.ToString()
}
else {
  $itempricestring = "$" + ($itemprice | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}
IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $taxstring = "$" + $tax.ToString()
}
else {
  $taxstring = "$" + ($tax | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}

$Result = $finalrice % 2
IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $finalricestring = "$" +$finalrice.ToString()
}
else {
  $finalricestring = "$" + ($finalrice | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}
```

Comment: Is  `'{0:f2}' -f $value` not all you need?

Comment: can you give me an example on how to use it :X 
The problem is that I have a double like 2.00, when I try to use it as a string or actually do .tostring it just remove the 0s

Answer (score 0):

$shippingpricestring = "$" + $shippingprice.ToString("#.##")

Scripting Guy Reference: [Hey Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/28/formatting-powershell-decimal-places/)

```
$shippingprice = 17.1111
$ItemPrice = 4.1211
$tax = 94.919
$finalrice =10.3211

$Result = $shippingprice % 2
IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $shippingpricestring = "$" + $shippingprice.ToString("#.##")
}
else {
  $shippingpricestring = "$" + ($shippingprice | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}

Write-Output $shippingpricestring

IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $itempricestring = "$" + $itemprice.ToString("#.##")
}
else {
 $itempricestring = "$" + ($itemprice | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}

Write-Output $itempricestring

IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $taxstring = "$" + $tax.ToString("#.##")
}
else {
  $taxstring = "$" + ($tax | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}

Write-Output $taxstring

$Result = $finalrice % 2
IF ($Result -ne 1 -and $Result -ne 0)
{
  $finalricestring = "$" +$finalrice.ToString("#.##")
}
else {
  $finalricestring = "$" + ($finalrice | % { '{0:0.00}' -f $_ })
}
Write-Output $finalricestring

RESULT
$17.11
$4.12
$94.92
$10.32
```

*** The above assumes that all the variables have more than 2 decimal spaces.  If say $tax = 9.9 $taxstring would appear as 9.9 and NOT as 9.90

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format the number with .ToString you can go with .ToString(format)

Example

```
$list = 1, 1.1, 1.111, 1.1111
$list | %{$_.ToString("0.00")}
```

Output

```
1.00
1.10
1.11
1.11
```

Comment: Amm that fixed it, but when I'm trying to do $0.00 as a string it'll just add to the current string instead of replacing it (I'm using regex to replace the prices on an html document)
$text -replace '(?<=Price">).*?(?=</)', $itempricestring | Set-Content -Path "ReceiptSample.html"
so if theres is $1.00 there, itll pur $1.00.0.00 instead of replacing the 1.